# Weird PIL behaviour in virtualenv - Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, virtualenv

I have a django application that requires PIL and I have been getting errors so I decided to play around with PIL on my hosting server.

PIL is installed in my virtual environment. However, when running the following I get an error, and when I run it outside the virtual environment it works.

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 16 2012, 15:47:14) 
[GCC 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import Image
>>> im  = Image.open('test.png')
>>> im
<PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=28x22 at 0x7F477CFFAE18>
>>> im.convert('RGB')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL-1.1.7-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/Image.py", line 679, in convert
    self.load()
  File "/opt/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL-1.1.7-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/ImageFile.py", line 189, in load
    d = Image._getdecoder(self.mode, d, a, self.decoderconfig)
  File "/opt/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL-1.1.7-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/Image.py", line 385, in _getdecoder
    raise IOError("decoder %s not available" % decoder_name)
IOError: decoder zip not available
>>>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely the Python you are using in your virtualenv has been built by yourself, not the system Python - is that right? If so your problem is that the header (.h) files for zlib are not installed in your system when building Python itself.

You have to have the "ziplib-devel" (or equivalent) package in Linux when building the Python you will use on your virtualenv. You can test if it works by trying to `import zlib` from the Python console.

As an alternative to rebuilding Python you can find your system's Python zip-related files and copy them to the Python used in your virtualenv (if they are the same Python version).

Comment: I was able to successfully `import zlib` in my virtuaelnv

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Pillow](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow) which is a repackaged PIL which plays much nicer with virtualenv.